# datetime comparison and datetime different of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm fail on simple datetime comparison and datetime different
my input is from jquery UI datetimepicker,

```
var dt1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val(); //2012-08-12 13:49
var dt2 = $('#datetimepicker2').val(); //2012-08-14 14:21
if( (dt1!="") && (dt2!="") ){
    var d1 = Date.parse(dt1); // return NaN
    var dd1 = new Date(Date.parse(dt1));    // return Invalid Date
    var ddd1 = dt1.getTime() // added this, the entire script no functioning
    alert (dt1 +":"+ d1 + ":"+ dd1 +"\n"+ ddd1);
}
```

anyone know what i did wrong here?
prefer solution of javascript.

Comment: Try [`$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('getDate')`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-getDate).

Comment: ok, with your suggestion i able to do comparison, but how to i do the datetime different? return...

d1 = 1344752760000
d2 = 1344753180000
d1 - d2 = 420000

Comment: Change `-` to `/`. Its more acceptable version.

e.g. `dt1 = dt1.replace(/-/g,'/');`

Comment: how to copy and paste my solution in "Comment"?
Where i paste over, it become - characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way as per the format provided in question `2012-08-12 13:49`

To find out the difference between two dates in days:hours:minutes you can do by this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6vNnN/4/)**

```
function ConvertMilliSecondsToTimeSpan(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        d = Math.floor(t / cd),
        h = '0' + Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
        m = '0' + Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
    return [d, h.substr(-2), m.substr(-2)].join(':');
}

var dt1 = Date.parse("2012-08-12 13:49");
var dt2 = Date.parse("2012-08-11 14:21");

alert("Difference: Days:Hours:Minutes " + ConvertMilliSecondsToTimeSpan(Math.abs(dt2 - dt1)));
​
```

Comment: I did according to format you provided, I have updated my answer with demo.

Comment: ok, date comparison is done , how about the datetime different?
base on the solution from diobe(above) he's answer is day basic, i wish to have return in the same format as well. example like
000-00-02 01:29 (2 days 1 hour 29 minute), i modifying his into in

Comment: I have added code for finding out the difference in days:hours:minutes, I hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt1 = "2012-08-12 13:49";
var dt2 = "2012-08-14 14:21";
if( (dt1!="") && (dt2!="") ){
    var d1 = new Date(dt1.split(" ").join("T")); 
    var d2 = new Date(dt2.split(" ").join("T"));
    var diff = d2 - d1; // difference in milliseconds

    //console.log(d1, d2, diff/(60*60*24*1000));
    alert(d1);
    alert(d2);
    if(diff > 0){
      alert(d1 + " before " + d2);
    }else if(diff < 0){
      alert(d2 + " before " + d1);
    }else{
      alert(d2 + " before " + d1);
    }
    alert(Math.abs(diff/(60*60*24*1000)).toFixed(2) + " days");

}
```

Comment: your code is running fine @ http://jsfiddle.net side, but if dt1 and dt2 from input text which having the jquery UI of datepicker, the entire function is not peforming, what from your code, i did i able to fine some solution, thanks

Comment: In that case actually it is very simple. You can use datepicker function to get the date : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/A5z5g/

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code it look like true somehow but it isn't. When parsing
from string, using Date.parse there is a format of string to be used. I tried to mention all.
Try to pass strings of the below format.

The format is: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ. The ‘Z’ part denotes an optional time zone. Subforms are also possible:

```
   <ol>
    <li>YYYY
    <li>YYYY-MM
    <li>YYYY-MM-DD
    <li>THH:mm   // example: 'T12:00'
    <li>THH:mm:ss
    <li>THH:mm:ss.sss
    </ol>
```

example:

```
var date1=Date.parse("2012-08-14");
var d = Date.parse("January 26, 2011 13:51:50");
var dd=var d = Date.parse('2011-01-26T13:51:50.417') ;
```

So Let apply to you question. This is working to me with the mentioned output

```
      //var dt1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val(); //2012-08-12 13:49
                   // var dt2 = $('#datetimepicker2').val(); //2012-08-14 14:21
           I realize that at least you are able to get dt1 and dt2 with values I assigned to date1 and date2, if so put the below code and see if you get the output .
        var date1 ="2012-08-12 13:49";
        var date2 ="2012-08-14 14:21";
        var dt1=date1.split(" ").join("T");//2012-08-12T13:49
        var dt2=date2.split(" ").join("T");//=>2012-08-14T14:21

        if((dt1!="") && (dt2!="")){
        alert(dt1);
            var d1 = Date.parse(dt1); // return good output  1344768540000
     var d2 = Date.parse(dt2);  //return 1344943260000 Now you can compare d1 and d2   values

var dd1 = new Date(Date.parse(dt1));  // returned  Sun Aug 12 2012 13:49:00 GMT+0300 (Egypt Standard Time)
            var ddd1 = dd1.getTime(); // work fine 1344768540000 dt1 is a string can't work here

            alert (dt1 +":"+ d1 + ":"+ dd1 +"\n"+ ddd1);   // return   2012-08-12T13:49:1344768540000:Sun Aug 12 2012 13:49:00 GMT+0300 (Egypt Standard Time)
        1344768540000
        }
```

Comment: sorry that, i'm not able to change input format coz it from jquery UI datepicker.

Comment: If you get dt1 and dt2 values as you commented just see the output when I try to edit your code. I think it work 100% as it is for me.

Comment: Now you can compare d1 and d2 as you see values

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clearn method, which produces no additional js Date objects or requires any parsing.

```
// get epoch of datepicker 1
var dt1 = $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('getDate').getTime(); 
// get epoch of datepicker 2
var dt2 = $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('getDate').getTime(); 
// ensure both evaluate to true
if(dt1 && dt2){
     if(dt1 < dt2){
        //dt1 is earlier
     }else if(dt1 > dt2){
        //dt1 is later
     }else{
        //dates are equal
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself doing a datetime heavy app, http://momentjs.com/ wraps the native Date object with a much more flexible API.